# Applying layer of JS before the HTML loads

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a .html loaded to clients. On it, jQuery does some modifications.

The problem is that the page loads in two steps: first the original .html, then, a fraction of a second later, the modified .html.

This approach causes jerkyness. Is there a way to show the .html only once JavaScript has acted upon it?

Comment: I'm changing all link elements (on the order of 100) into button elements. Takes almost no time on my computer, but I can definitely see jerkyness.

Comment: I would really advice against that. Links are meant to be links, while buttons are buttons. Links should redirect you to a different page, while buttons should preform actions on the same page, or act as form controls. You shouldn't mix the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you MUST do this, then something like this:

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    myfunction();
    $("#wrapper").show();
}
```

CSS:

```
div#wrapper{ display: none; }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <!-- my page stuff that i dont want to be jerky -->
</div>
```

However, I would raelly advise that you find a way to apply the styles/data to the page before you generate it (e.g. with PHP, ASP etc.),

Comment: Thanks. The problem with this approach is that the CSS is *also* applied after the initial .html loads. So I still have the same problem, but this time with CSS (which is in an external file).

Comment: This is pretty much how every modern website is laid out. The browser will load the resources in the <head> section (css) and then apply it - you do not see the unformatted HTML then the CSS applied HTML. If you really believe that, then just have `<div style="display: none;">`

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS to set default properties of the parts you are changing, if these are stylistic changes and not HTML changes.

You can also use jQuery's .load() to reload page fragments instead of the whole page.

Or, use css to set `body { display: none; }` and using `(document).ready()` to `$('body').show()`.

Comment: Thanks. The problem with this approach is that the CSS is also applied after the initial .html loads. So I still have the same problem, but this time with CSS (which is in an external file).